# Cannot deactivate Firewall Stealth Mode

Tags: macos, firewall

Probably after last macOS upgrade I cannot deactivate Stealth Mode in Firewall options. Even if I deactivate it, after system restart it is active.

Is there any possibility to disable stealth mode from command line?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that helped was to reset Firewall from terminal with:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw \
  --setblockall off \
  --setallowsigned on \
  --setallowsignedapp on \
  --setloggingmode on \
  --setstealthmode on \
  --setglobalstate on
```

Comment: Nice work - sometimes the command line is the only way to reset some things.